# Definition of 'симпатичный'

Tags: значения

Could I have some explanation about the word 'симпатичный'? In some contexts it seems to mean attractive and others it seems to be sympathetic. For example: “Цилиндр тихо прозвенел в ответ, остановился, потух, и в комнату вошла полная симпатичная женщина в белом чистом халате и сказала Ивану..."

Also, how does 'симпатичный' compare to 'привлекательный' in meaning?

Comment: Don't over analyze this word. It simply means good looking.

Answer (score 3):

*Симпатия* is a false friend of English "sympathy": it means "liking, fondness".

Likewise, *симпатичный* means "lovely, likeable".

Russian for "sympathy" would be *сочувствие, сострадание, взаимопонимание*, the first word being the Slavic calque of the Greek ancestor to the English word.

I can hardly imagine any context where "sympathy" could be translated as *симпатия* (or "sympathetic" as *симпатичный*).

> Also, how does 'симпатичный' compare to 'привлекательный' in meaning?

*Привлекательный* is a calque of some cognate of "attractive" and means the same.

The two words are quite close in meaning, but *привлекательный* has more sexual connotation.

*Симпатичная бабуля* would mean "lovely old lady"; *привлекательная бабуля* would mean "attractive old lady". It would be weird to call an old lady attractive.

Comment: I'd probably lose the "sexual connotation".  Food can be "attractive", or a house.

Comment: @VictorBazarov: I think he's referring to the Russian word привлекательный. Can food and houses be this?

Comment: @CocoPop: you can say *привлекательная цена* or *привлекательные условия*. But when referring to a person, it means they are sexually attractive.

Answer (score 2):

> For example: “Цилиндр тихо прозвенел в ответ, остановился, потух, и в
>   комнату вошла полная симпатичная женщина в белом чистом халате и
>   сказала Ивану..."

"Симпатичный" -- at least in this case -- means that the narrator liked the way this woman looked, but didn't find her an *extremely* beautiful woman. There is, however, nothing bad about this word.

> Also, how does 'симпатичный' compare to 'привлекательный' in meaning?

I think that "привлекательный" would be the word to describe a person that is beautiful according to the standard views on beauty. The word is made the same way as the English "attractive" <- "attract": "привлекательный" <- "привлекать".
If someone is "cимпатичный/ая", you like their looks, but perhaps they don't look like people in fashion magazine.

Comment: Можно сравнить 'привлекательный' со словом 'благовидный/благообразный?'

Comment: Можно. :) Слово "благообразный" намного реже, звучит чуть-чуть архаично. Например, думаю, что можно сказать "благообразный старец" (поправьте, если ошибаюсь!). Но это значит совсем другое: старец, который выглядит очень хорошим (с моральной точки зрения), спокойным... Что-то вроде respectable.

Comment: @Конрад: "Благовидный" -- тоже совсем другой смысл. Можно, например, найти благовидный предлог (excuse) что-то не делать. В современном языке как синоним "привлекательного" не употребляется.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this is an English issue as much as a Russian one.

The main Russian use of *симпатичный* (*"good looking"*) *and* the main  main English use (*"compassion"*) are both different than the main European ones like *sympathisch*/*simpático*/*sympathique* etc,  (*"friendly"*, *"pleasant"* or *"nice"*).

The Russian meaning comes from the common European one, probably all from French.  The English meaning is really the most correct, etymologically.  (The literal component parts of *sympathy*, *compassion*, *сочувствие* are the same (*"with"* + *"feeling"*).)  But both are false friends.

Comment: This applies only to a full adjective "симпатичный". Both noun "симпатия" and short adjective "симпатичен" are of "European flavour" meaning rather "friendly/pleasant" without any sexual connotation.

Comment: Very good point. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is 'good looking' (if 'sympathetic', then not in meanings close to "сочувствующий"). The difference with "привлекательный" is that it might be just personal *impression*, not necessarily based on general attractiveness of the mentioned one. "Привлекательный" expresses the idea that the person is definitely attractive to the others as well.